# Queue Deployments Using DX Requires Setup in UI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, queue, sfdx-error

I have a queue for new opps that looks like this:

```
<Queue xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <doesSendEmailToMembers>true</doesSendEmailToMembers>
    <email>newOpportunity@companyname.com</email>
    <name>New Opportunity</name>
    <queueSobject>
        <sobjectType>Case</sobjectType>
    </queueSobject>
    <queueSobject>
        <sobjectType>Task</sobjectType>
    </queueSobject>
</Queue>
```

When deploying this queue through DX to fresh scratch org, I get this error:

`New_Opportunity has not been setup to support the object: Task.  This must be configured in the setup UI Queues editor.`

Based on my research, DX does support deploying queues and definitely supports retrieving them.

If I make the queue in the org, this deploys just fine. It seems like the deployment is unable to update the objects supported.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior and is there a workaround?

Comment: were you just deploying the queue? Is the queue referenced anywhere else in your metadata (ex. List View)?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - In this case, I was deploying all metadata. The queues are referenced elsewhere.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - Played around with this last night. The UI is only required when and email address is attached to the queue and email members is true. Maybe a bug? Its a weird behavior to have different outcomes if email is true.